# Protect Windows VPN from Unauthorized Users

Tags: security, vpn

I have a VPN connection that I use while away from home to remote into my home network. I would use a zero config solution like Hamachi, but need access from my mobile device. Therefore, I have my Windows Home Server acting as the VPN server and will accept incoming connections. Both the username and password are strong. However, I'm worried about brute force attacks against my network. Is there something else that I should do to protect my network from having unauthorized access attempts to my network?

I'm familiar with Linux's FAIL2BAN, but wasn't sure if something similar existing for Windows.

[image]

Comment: mobile device - what kind of connection it uses?

Comment: PPTP (PPP encryption(MPPE))

Comment: kobaltz I mean connection to the internet, not to your home network

Comment: Oh. It's on a cell wireless 4G.

Comment: Then most likely it is getting the IP address from a constant range. You can ask your provider what range(s) they are using to assign addresses for 4G clients and allow connections only from these ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't outline to what extent you want/need to protect your home network. So I'll outline some broad things to consider.

First, and this is an absolute must: Ensure you are NOT using MS-CHAPv2 (or any other version). As of this summer, MS-CHAPv2 can now be [reliably and consistently broken](https://www.cloudcracker.com/blog/2012/07/29/cracking-ms-chap-v2/) 100% of the time.

Second, consider using [RADIUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS) for additional authentication and logging mechanism rather than using the default Windows userid/password scheme. Microsft RADIUS guide [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731108.aspx).  [FreeRADIUS](http://freeradius.org/) is a good implementation.

Third, consider two-factor authentication using something like a token. There's both hardware and software tokens. Two examples of software tokens. [iPhone](http://code.google.com/p/oathtoken/) and [PC client.](http://www.wikidsystems.com/) And an example of a hardware token vendor [here](http://www.rcdevs.com/).

Next, once clients connect, consider using [quarantine control](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441526.aspx) to slow or delay unauthorized users from quickly accessing resources.  If an unauthorized user were to defeat your access controls, your quarantine controls would hopefully reject or isolate them to prevent any malicious acts.

Last, here are some of Microsoft's recommendations. [VPN best practices here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778749%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). And security recommendations [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc995071.aspx).